# letting users create object themselves (prototype pollution)

Tags: javascript

Let's say if there's some object and an array

```
let a = [];
let settings= {
"admin":{"Admin":false},
"language": e // e is user input
}

a[f] = settings // f is user input
```

The user gets determined if they're admin or not via `a.admin.Admin`
and the language key value is controlled by the user's input which will turn into an object via the function JSON.parse

Will an attacker be able to change the object in the `admin` key value to `{"Admin":true}` via the parsed object in `language` ? and could there possibly be some prototype pollution occurring in this code?

Thank you.

Comment: What users your mean? How is it related to security? I suggest to close the question. When you reformulate the question, we can reopen it.

Comment: I have edited the post to make it more understandable, please tell me if there are still more confusion in the context.

Comment: What attacker you mean? What is the target of the attacker? If you mean some operating system, how is JSON related to the operating system? There are 1000 questions more. Your text does not explain anything.

Comment: @mentallurg the code is obviously in a js syntax and I’m talking about node js backend here. The server running on http and the user inputting their inputs through get or post request. It obviously seems like you don’t understand what I’m talking about.

Comment: Such code can also be executed in browser. Since JavaScript usage in browsers is the biggest field where JavaScript is used everyone would suppose that your are talking about browsers. May be you don't know anything except of Node.js. But people with at least some experience know that JavaScript can also be executed in Java and .NET, even if it is not so broad. So I still have no idea what are you talking about. Since your question seems to be about JavaScript only, it is **off-topic** on Security SE site. I suggest to move it to SO.